# How to trigger the CheckBox's unknown-name OnCheckedChanged even in c# and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a function, input a checkbox, but I don't know how to trigger his unknown-name OnCheckedChanged even.

The code look like below:

```
private void ConEnable(CheckBox MyCheckBox, TextBox MyTextBox, bool MyBool) 
{
    MyCheckBox.Enabled = MyBool;
    MyTextBox.Enabled = MyBool;
    if (!MyBool) {// == false
        MyCheckBox.Checked = MyBool;
        MyTextBox.Text = "";
        //MyCheckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(...);
    }
}
```

//the other OnCheckedChanged even of CheckBox2 and CheckBox3...：

```
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ConEnable(CheckBox1, TextBox1, !CheckBox2.Checked);
    ConEnable(CheckBox3, CheckBox2.Checked);
    ConEnable(CheckBox4, TextBox8, TextBox9, CheckBox2.Checked);
    ConEnable(CheckBox5, CheckBox2.Checked);
    //if (!CheckBox2.Checked) {
    //  ConEnable(CheckBox6, TextBox3, false);
    //  ConEnable(CheckBox7, TextBox4, TextBox5, false);
    //  ConEnable(CheckBox8, TextBox6, TextBox7, false);
    //}
    SetResult1();
  }
  protected void CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ConEnable(CheckBox4, TextBox8, TextBox9, !CheckBox3.Checked);
    ConEnable(CheckBox5, !CheckBox3.Checked);
    ConEnable(CheckBox6, TextBox3, CheckBox3.Checked);
    ConEnable(CheckBox7, TextBox4, TextBox5, CheckBox3.Checked);
    ConEnable(CheckBox8, TextBox6, TextBox7, CheckBox3.Checked);
    if (!CheckBox3.Checked) {
      ConEnable(CheckBox6, TextBox3, false);
      ConEnable(CheckBox7, TextBox4, TextBox5, false);
      ConEnable(CheckBox8, TextBox6, TextBox7, false);
    }
    SetResult1();
  }
```

I hope it can trigger those even like below:
EX：
I uncheck CheckBox2 (CheckBox2 become false)->trigger CheckBox2_CheckedChanged and CheckBox3 become false through the ConEnable function -> **trigger MyCheckBox's even (i.e. CheckBox3_CheckedChanged)** in ConEnable.->CheckBox6 become false and  **trigger MyCheckBox's even (i.e. CheckBox6_CheckedChanged)** in ConEnable->........

Answer (score 0):

Type : `[Object Name].[Event]+=` and then press tab twice to create the event's method.

P.S. Object Name is different than Object Type

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you are having hard time understanding how to know which checkbox has triggered the event.

In code below you can see that we are creating event listener to `CheckedChanged` event to **any** checkbox that is being passed into your method and we do not need to know anything about it. When this checkbox will trigger `CheckedChanged` event, method `CheckChangedEventHandler` will be fired, this method will always accept 2 parameters `object sender, EventArgs e`. `sender` is your checkbox, `EventArgs e` in object that has additional information about occurrence of event.
You then can cast `sender` to `CheckBox` and use it for whatever purposes you wish.

```
MyCheckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs >(CheckChangedEventHandler); 

 void CheckChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //sender is your checkbox;
            var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void ConEnable(CheckBox MyCheckBox, TextBox MyTextBox, bool MyBool) 
{
   MyCheckBox.Enabled = MyBool;
   MyTextBox.Enabled = MyBool;
   if (!MyBool) {// == false
   MyCheckBox.Checked = MyBool;
   MyTextBox.Text = "";
   MyCheckBox.CheckedChanged += mycheckbox_Changed;
}

  protected void mycheckbox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
  }
```

Comment: I try your code.However, it seems like to add the mycheckbox_Changed to CheckedChanged. Could I trigger MyCheckBox's even in ConEnable function?

Comment: you must to register userdefined method( mycheckbox_Changed)   which have the same delegate signature  to corresponding event.So when ever you trigger the event ,it will fire.Please ensure that the control's autopost property must be true.So from your above question,you can trigger the checkedchanged event after you register the method in ConEnable function.

Comment: It is nice to add checkedchanged event in page_load.